# laravel image validation always fail

Tags: laravel, image, validation, file-upload, laravel-validation

I have problem to validate my image. Its ok on another project but in new project Laravel 8 always fail.

View:

```html
<label class="btn btn-primary" for="img" style="margin-top: 25px">upload image</label>
<input type="file" id="img" name="avatar" accept="image/*" hidden/>
```

Controller:

```php
$validated = $request->validate([
  'avatar' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
]);
```

Error:

> The avatar must be an image.
> The avatar must be a file of type: jpeg, png, jpg, gif, svg.

I try to remove image and max size but still error.

Comment: Does your `<form>` element have `enctype="multipart/form-data"`? Or is this an AJAX request? Please include the code you're using to send this file to the Controller for validation, either your `<form>` element or the `$.post()` (or similar) JS code.

Comment: thanks team i forgot to set enctype="multipart/form-data" to my form tag u save me :) after 2 hour serching tnx

Comment: No problem! It's a mistake we've all made, happy to help :)